# In pentaho ,during Configuring a Tomcat Server in Eclipse i cant build dev-rebuild file in ant

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ivy, pentaho

I am working on ubuntu OS,I have started working on pentaho-BI using eclipse..
Just started with this step by step configuration as mentioned in this link:[pentaho startup](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/01.+Setting+Up+Your+Environment+in+2.0)

I have checked out bi-project

but i found problem while Configuring a Tomcat Server in Eclipse using Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher...3rd step of given link:[Configuring a Tomcat Server in Eclipse using Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/05.+Debugging+with+Tomcat+in+Eclipse+IDE+in+2.0+using+Sysdeo+Eclipse+Tomcat+Launcher)..

some IVY get resolved but then error in building and build failed...:(

the output is as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::

[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS

[ivy:resolve]       module not found: pentaho#pentaho-open-admin-console-package;2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried

[ivy:resolve]     /home/hardik/.ivy2/local/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml

[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact pentaho#pentaho-open-admin-console-package;2.0.0-

SNAPSHOT!pentaho-open-admin-console-package.jar:

[ivy:resolve]     /home/hardik/.ivy2/local/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[ivy:resolve]   ==== shared-ivy: tried

[ivy:resolve]     ttp://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ivy.xml

[ivy:resolve]   ==== shared-mvn: tried

[ivy:resolve]     ttp://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact pentaho#pentaho-open-admin-console-package;2.0.0-SNAPSHOT!pentaho-open-admin-console-package.jar:

[ivy:resolve]     ttp://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[ivy:resolve]   ==== public: tried

[ivy:resolve]     ttp://repo1.maven.org/maven2/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact pentaho#pentaho-open-admin-console-package;2.0.0-SNAPSHOT!pentaho-open-admin-console-package.jar:

[ivy:resolve]     ttp://repo1.maven.org/maven2/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/pentaho-open-admin-console-package-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[ivy:resolve]       :: pentaho#pentaho-open-admin-console-package;2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[ivy:resolve]

[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED

/home/hardik/workspace/bi-platform-v2/branches/2.0/bi-platform-build/dev_build.xml:84: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/home/hardik/workspace/bi-platform-v2/branches/2.0/bi-platform-assembly/common.xml:194: impossible to resolve dependencies:

```
resolve failed - see output for details
```

Total time: 27 seconds

As i cant put more than 2 links, i have removed h from all http, its not a mistake..

Comment: Errm, 2.0 is very very old.  you should really be looking at 4.5.0-stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like version 2.0-SNAPSHOT is available from the repository. See:

- http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/pentaho/pentaho-open-admin-console-package/

I'd suggest editing the project's ivy.xml file and revising the revision. Perhaps use "2.0.0.stable" instead?